# MySQL simplifying a Select & Update command

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-update

I am making a simple message system feature for my website, where logged on members can send messages to each other, to do this I am using two tables authors(my users table) and messages. They are described below:

Authors:

```
aId int(20) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
aUser   varchar(30) NO  UNI NULL    
aPass   varchar(40) NO      NULL    
aEmail  varchar(30) NO  UNI NULL    
aBio    mediumtext  YES     NULL    
aReg    datetime    NO      NULL
```

Messages:

```
msgId   int(20) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
mSender int(20) NO  MUL NULL    
mReciever   int(20) NO  MUL NULL    
mTitle  tinytext    NO      NULL    
mBody   mediumtext  NO      NULL    
mRead   tinyint(4)  NO      NULL    
mDate   datetime    NO      NULL
```

I also have a constraint foreign key in `messages (mReciever) REFERENCES authors(aId));`
Currently when a logged on user wants to message another user the html form has a “username, message” input elements - very simple. For submit execution - First the php script queries the authors table using a select command to check if the user exists and then get the user id from the result set, the second part of the php script can then use the aId from the result set in the insert command on the messages table. While this is working, I was wondering if there would be a more simplified /elegant solution perhaps combing both MySQL commands into one to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
Insert into Messages (mReceiver, mBody) Values ((select aId from Authors where aUser = @user), @message)
```

where @user is the username and @message is the message.

Comment: Thanks you Chris K. I replaced the mentioned block of code with the sub query you suggested and it worked a treat. Many thanks for your help.